# Building a static program on Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have built qt-6.6-static on Windows and I would like to build a project or two as static. I have tried to build an example program "Scenegraph" but it fails with error messages.

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Qt/6.6.0-static/plugins/networkinformation/libqnetworklistmanager.a(qnetworklistmanagerevents.cpp.obj):qnetworklistmanagerevents.cpp:(.text$_ZN25QNetworkListManagerEvents24checkBehindCaptivePortalEv+0x82): undefined reference to `__imp_VariantInit'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Qt/6.6.0-static/plugins/networkinformation/libqnetworklistmanager.a(qnetworklistmanagerevents.cpp.obj):qnetworklistmanagerevents.cpp:(.text$_ZN25QNetworkListManagerEvents24checkBehindCaptivePortalEv+0x98): undefined reference to `__imp_VariantClear'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Qt/6.6.0-static/plugins/networkinformation/libqnetworklistmanager.a(qnetworklistmanagerevents.cpp.obj):qnetworklistmanagerevents.cpp:(.text$_ZN25QNetworkListManagerEvents24checkBehindCaptivePortalEv+0x1d9): undefined reference to `__imp_VariantClear'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Qt/6.6.0-static/plugins/networkinformation/libqnetworklistmanager.a(qnetworklistmanagerevents.cpp.obj):qnetworklistmanagerevents.cpp:(.text$_ZN25QNetworkListManagerEvents24checkBehindCaptivePortalEv+0x24d): undefined reference to `__imp_VariantClear'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Compiler I am using is gcc 13.2.0

Apparently this would suggest that I should be linking to oleaut32.lib but the qt files already do that. Tested the oleaut lib in debug mode and it appeared to be working.

```
QT += quick
QT += opengl
CONFIG += c++2a
CONFIG += static
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++2a
LIBS += -lgmp

SOURCES += \
    Squircle.cpp \
    glrenderer.cpp \
    main.cpp \

RESOURCES += \
    qml.qrc

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    Squircle.h \
    glrenderer.h \

DISTFILES += main.qml
```

Anyone else struggled with this? Any solutions other than "use dynamic build" ?

//Added edit because of the comment

I forgot to mention that I have tried adding the link LIBS +=-loleaut32 still got the same error.

Also this is some of the compile output. So surely the link is already there.

```
libqwindows.a -ldwmapi -limm32 -loleaut32 -lsetupapi -lshlwapi -lwinspool
lib/libQt6Network.a -lbrotlidec -lbrotlicommon
```

Comment: If they do that, you wouldn't get an error. Try manually linking to oleaut32.lib